# Apply class as active in the list item using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How to add the class as active in li using jquery. i dont have any idea about that.i have tried many times, but am not getting expected output. i have write sample code here, please check my code and let me know anything else.

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree">
        <li class="treeview">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-table"></i> <span>Tables</span>
            <span class="pull-right-container">
              <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
            </span>
          </a>
          <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li><a href="simple.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Simple tables</a></li>
            <li><a href="data.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Data tables</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>        
      </ul>
```

How to apply the class as active in li. Need to get the output like this. please do my  needs.

```
    <ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree">
<li class="treeview active">
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-table"></i> <span>Tables</span>
    <span class="pull-right-container">
      <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
    </span>
  </a>
  <ul class="treeview-menu menu-open">
    <li><a href="simple.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Simple tables</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="data.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Data tables</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: where's your jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is:

```
$('li').on('click', function(){
  $('.active').removeClass(); //removes .active class from currently active li
  $(this).addClass('active'); //sets this element .active
});
```

//Edit: There's a working below. Class `active` makes particular `<li>` color red.

```js
$('li').on('click', function(){
      $('.active').removeClass(); //removes .active class from currently active li
      $(this).addClass('active'); //sets this element .active
    });
```

```css
li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
<li>one</li>
<li>two</li>
<li>three</li>
</ul>
```